# Performance Difference Between Explicitly Committing vs Auto-Committing Transactions in MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In MySQL, I can nest a series of transactions atomically with the following:

```
START TRANSACTIONS;

UPDATE balance
SET current_balance = 40
WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE balance
SET current_balance = 50
WHERE id = 2;

COMMIT;
```

I can do the same thing in SQL Server with

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE balance
SET current_balance = 40
WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE balance
SET current_balance = 50
WHERE id = 2;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Is there a difference in how fast queries are executed in the above vs not nesting (no START / BEGIN and COMMIT commands) the statements in their respective database systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using explicit transactions should be faster especially if you do a lot of inserts or updates.

- For implicit transaction (autocommit = 1 in MySQL), database engine have to write transaction log to disk (or disk cache for that matter) after each statement.
- For explicit transaction (autocommit = 0 in MySQL), database engine can potentially have only one input/output operation for writing transaction log for all statements used in a transaction.

IMHO it won't be noticeable in just two update statements though.

But **transactions mainly are not about speed** but rather consistency and atomicity of the whole operation.

---

BTW in MySQL you can simultaneously update two records without explicitly starting a transaction in a following way

```
UPDATE balance b1 JOIN balance b2
    ON b1.id = 1 
   AND b2.id = 2
   SET b1.current_balance = 40,
       b2.current_balance = 50
```

or both in MySQL and SQL Server

```
UPDATE balance 
   SET CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 40 
               WHEN 2 THEN 50
       END
 WHERE id IN(40, 50)
```

Further reading:

- [WRITELOG waittype - Implicit vs. Explicit Transaction: disk or coding issue?](http://sqltouch.blogspot.com/2013/05/writelog-waittype-implicit-vs-explicit.html)
- [Implicit and explicit transactions](http://stanleyjohns.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/implicit-and-explicit-transactions/)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific by what you mean when you say they don't need overhead for flushing?

Comment: That means that when using explicit transactions changes that you've made are not made permanent immediately. On the contrary when in an autocommit mode changes are made permanent (table changes being flushed to disk) after each statement.

Comment: So flushing 1000 update statements separately would be slower than flushing 1 explicit transaction with 1000 update statements?

Comment: Exactly. Thats why it's advisable when you make a lot of inserts or updates do it one statement or disable autocommit and use explicit transactions.

Answer (score 1):

By Default SQL Server Guarantees Atomicity for Sql Statements but to enforce Atomicity on Sql Batches(More then one sql statement) Transactions are used.

Explicit Transaction are not used to gain any performance but to Control Atomicity among different Operations/Sql Statements wrapped inside a Transaction, So we have the control of multiple operations done on the target data to COMMIT them all or ROLLBACK all, and data is not left in half done state.

Yes Explicit Transaction can have impact on the performance, as resources being used inside an Explicit transaction are locked by the transaction and not available for other users. Also the behaviour of transaction is different under different Transaction Isolation Levels.